# How to save the latest url requests in django?

Tags: django, django-middleware

I'd like to add a 'Last seen' url list to a project, so that last 5 articles requested by users can be displayed in the list to all users. 
I've read the middleware [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/) but could not figure out how to use it in my case. 
What I need is a simple working example of a middleware that captures the requests so that they can be saved and reused.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in middleware? I am not sure it is the best place.

Comment: @albar I'm open to all suggestions to do the task. Actually I prefer a view, as I'm not familiar with middleware writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, don't know if I would do it with middleware, or right a decorator. But as your question is about Middleware, here my example:

```
class ViewLoggerMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # We only want to save successful responses
        if response.status_code not in [200, 302]:
            return response

        ViewLogger.objects.create(user_id=request.user.id, 
            view_url=request.get_full_path(), timestamp=timezone.now())
```

Showing Top 5 would be something like;

```
ViewLogger.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).order_by("-timestamp")[:5]
```

Note: Code is not tested, I'm not sure if status_code is a real attribute of response. Also, you could change your list of valid status codes.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  However this one has the problem that logs all request, including request to urls that I don't want to save. I just want to limit to request to certain content (e.g.`/articles/*` and `/posts/*`). How would you do it without middleware?

Comment: As I said, you could right your own decorator function, and place it above fuctions you want to monitor. An other "simple" option is to add an extra if to the middleware `if "/articles/" in request.path`.